# Combine options and variable inline with builtin `read`

Tags: bash

Suppose such a mininal example

```
    $ read -p "Enter a numeral: "
    Enter a numeral: 4
    $ echo $REPLY
    4
```

In the above, there's no variable listed, `REPLY` be assigned to input automatically.

I'd like to list a variale like:

```
    $ read  foo -p "Enter a numeral: "
    4
    -bash: read: `-p': not a valid identifier
```

How to achieve it not invoking echo command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
read -p "Enter a numeral: " foo
```

variable to assign **after** options